# Threads constantly interrupting each other, log doesn't reflect system operations

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

I built a system that simulates memory paging, just like an MMU.
And to better regulate and understand how it works, I am logging it.

My problem is that it seems the log is not accurately reflecting the operations of the system, or rather it does, but then I have a big problem with threads that I need some help solving.

I'll try and explain.

```
public void run() //gets pages and writes to them
{ // i printed the pageId of every process to check they are running at the same time and competing for resources
    for(ProcessCycle currentCycle : processCycles.getProcessCycles())
    {
        Long[] longArray = new Long[currentCycle.getPages().size()];
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i < currentCycle.getPages().size();i++)
            {
                MMULogger.getInstance().write("GP:P" + id + " " + currentCycle.getPages().get(i) + " " + Arrays.toString(currentCycle.getData().get(i)), Level.INFO);
            }
            Page<byte[]>[] newPages = mmu.getPages(currentCycle.getPages().toArray(longArray));
            List<byte[]> currentPageData = currentCycle.getData();
            System.out.println("process id " + id);
            for(int i = 0; i < newPages.length;i++)
            {
                byte[] currentData = currentPageData.get(i);
                newPages[i].setContent(currentData);
            }
            Thread.sleep(currentCycle.getSleepMs());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this code snippet is taken from a class called Process. Just like in a computer, I have multiple processes, and they each need to read and write from pages, which they request from the class called MMU. this is the "mmu.getpages" part.

We also write to our log file inside the method get pages:

```
public synchronized Page<byte[]>[] getPages(java.lang.Long[] pageIds) throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Page<byte[]>[] toReturn = new Page[pageIds.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < pageIds.length; i++)
    {
        Long currentPage = algo.getElement(pageIds[i]);
        if(currentPage == null) //page not found in RAM
        {
            if(ram.getInitialCapacity() != ram.getNumOfPages()) //ram is NOT full
            {
                MMULogger.getInstance().write("PF:"+pageIds[i], Level.INFO);
                algo.putElement(Long.valueOf(pageIds[i]),Long.valueOf(pageIds[i]));
                ram.addPage(HardDisk.getInstance().pageFault(pageIds[i]));
            }
            else //ram is full
            {
                Long IDOfMoveToHdPage = algo.putElement(pageIds[i], pageIds[i]);
                Page<byte[]> moveToHdPage = ram.getPage((int)((long)IDOfMoveToHdPage));
                Page<byte[]> moveToRAM = HardDisk.getInstance().pageReplacement(moveToHdPage, pageIds[i]);
                ram.removePage(moveToHdPage);
                ram.addPage(moveToRAM);
                MMULogger.getInstance().write("PR: MTH " + moveToHdPage.getPageId() + " MTR " + moveToRAM.getPageId(), Level.INFO);
            }
        }
        toReturn[i] = ram.getPage((int)((long)pageIds[i]));
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

So all in all to recap - a process requests pages, I write to the log file which process requests which page and what it wants to write to it, and then I call mmu.getpages, and the logic of the system continues.

My problem is that the log looks like this:

```
GP:P2 5 [102, 87, -9, 85, -5]
GP:P1 1 [-9, -18, 50, -124, -102]
GP:P4 10 [79, -51, 67, 118, 111]
GP:P2 6 [-20, -22, 3, -74, -65]
GP:P3 7 [90, 56, 91, 71, -115]
PF:5
GP:P6 18 [28, -39, -3, 64, -117]
GP:P5 13 [72, -26, 52, -84, 6]
GP:P4 11 [-55, -70, -88, -9, 38]
GP:P1 2 [39, 112, -117, 5, 109]
GP:P5 12 [38, -31, 18, -40, 36]
```

which is not what I wanted. At first you can see process 2 requested page 5 and wanted to write to it [102, 87, -9, 85, -5].

After that line, I would have expected to see "PF:5" but its further down. I think it is the case because process 2 ran out of time and didnt manage to finish mmu.getpages operation. so it never printed PF:5 to the file.

That is a problem for me. I want the processes to run simultaneously in a multithreaded fashion, but i want the log to be of the form:

```
GP:P2 5 [1,1,1,1,1]
PF:5
GP:P2 7 [1,2,3,4,5]
PF:7
GP:P19 12 [0,0,0,0,0]
PF:12
```

For example

Comment: "this code snippet is taken from a class called Process" Is it `java.lang.Process`?

Comment: no. It is my own class which I wrote which is called Process